# use sed to add multiple strings between strings

Tags: string, command-line, sed

I was playing around with sed to do an operation on a text. The input is something like:

```
가가라  a b a e
블랙  c dd we df
사무소    as le we
```

I need to add some formats on it so the output should be:

```
id { id: "가가라" } value { val: "a b a e"} word { word: "가가라"}
id { id: "블랙" } value { val: "c dd we df"} word { word: "블랙"}
id { id: "사무소" } value { val: "as le we"} word { word: "사무소"}
```

The question is, I know how to add the strings before and after the stings:

add strings at the beginning of the string:

```
sed 's/^/id \{ id: \"/'
```

add strings at the end of the string:

```
sed 's/$/\"\} word \{ word: \"/'
```

However, when I tried to add the characters 가가라 at the end of each line, this command I tried didn't work:

```
sed -r 's/(id\s\{\sid:\s\")([^a-z]*)[\sa-z]{1,10}(\"\}\sword\s\{\sword:\s\")/\1\2\3\2/'
```

Also I'm not sure how to add strings between string 가가라 and a b a e. I tried to use regular expression but seems like it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your sed line, it seems that you got confused with matching pattern and replacement.

try this sed line:

```
sed -r 's/(\S+)\s*(.*)/id { id: "\1" } value { val: "\2"} word { word: "\1"}/' file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  echo "가가라  a b a e
블랙  c dd we df
사무소    as le we"|sed -r 's/(\S+)\s*(.*)/id { id: "\1" } value { val: "\2"} word { word: "\1"}/'                             
id { id: "가가라" } value { val: "a b a e"} word { word: "가가라"}
id { id: "블랙" } value { val: "c dd we df"} word { word: "블랙"}
id { id: "사무소" } value { val: "as le we"} word { word: "사무소"}
```

Comment: I see.. yes I did confuse with the concepts of replacement and pattern. Need to practice more. XieXie:)